# SFMC SOAP API Server-to-Server Integrations

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I'm trying to create a QueryDefinition through the SOAP API using a new `Server-to-Server Integration`.  I can successfully generate an `access_token` through the `TENANT_ENDPOINT.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token` endpoint but am unable to use it in any requests.

This is the SOAP envelope being generated

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <fueloauth> [ACCESS TOKEN FROM AUTH REQUEST] </fueloauth>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <tns:CreateRequest>
      <tns:Objects xsi:type="ns1:QueryDefinition" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <tns:Name>Sample Query</tns:Name>
        <tns:CustomerKey>SamlpeQueryKey</tns:CustomerKey>
        <tns:QueryText>SELECT * FROM [QueryDefinitionTest]</tns:QueryText>
        <tns:TargetType>DE</tns:TargetType>
        <tns:DataExtensionTarget>
          <tns:CustomerKey>QueryDefinitionTest</tns:CustomerKey>
          <tns:Name>QueryDefinitionTest</tns:Name>
        </tns:DataExtensionDarget>
        <tns:TargetUpdateType>Overwrite</tns:TargetUpdateType>
      </tns:Objects>
    </tns:CreateRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the error being returned from SFMC

```
<soap:Fault>
  <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
  <faultstring>User not authorized</faultstring>       
  <faultactor>https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</faultfactor>
  <detail>
    <apifault xmlns="urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com">
      <Code>11</Code>
      <Message>User not authorized</Message>
    </apifault>
  </detail>
</soap:Fault>
```

Has something on the SOAP API changed that I haven't found in the docs?  I'm not authenticating through a user so the error message doesn't give me an indication as to what is going on.

Comment: Did you set the API user checkbox for the user you are using?

Comment: Are you using the new `soap_instance_url` when making your soap calls? This authentication will not work with any legacy endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue is discussed here:

[Can I use an OAuth 2.0 token for API Integration in Enhanced Packages in the Soap API fueloauth token header](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252030/can-i-use-an-oauth-2-0-token-for-api-integration-in-enhanced-packages-in-the-soa)

I also encountered the same problem. SOAP Webservice seems to expect a user-based authentication, but server-to-server integrations cannot be configured to feature one, as the clientId and clientSecret are not connected to a user.

If you change your integration to use the "security header" with username and password instead of YOURTOKEN, SOAP calls in the new API Framework do work. The user whose name & password you enter needs to be an API user.

This is merely a workaround though, not a solution.

Here are the details on the security header:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/authenticate-soap-api.htm

Comment: ..or you can just use the v1/requestToken endpoint for SOAP and the new v2/token endpoint for REST - no need to utilize user/pass authentication as it is not nearly as efficient or secure as the OAuth tokens.

Comment: I was hoping that there was something I was missing but it appears I wasn't.  Thanks for sharing the workaround.

@Gortonington - Wouldn't I need to have 2 Installed Packages in order to use both auth endpoints?

Comment: That is correct - but you would need to have an API user created to utilize the User/Pass as well. It is really tom-a-to, to-mah-to.